# unable to retrieve overlayicons for dialog box window in my visual studio application

Tags: windows, icons, overlay, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm trying to display overlay icons on specific set of files in explorer window.

I have written `shellextensionhandler` class which has `ismemberof()`,`getoverlayinfo()` and `getpriority()` functions and it works fine if I open a new window in explorer, all these APIs are getting hit and overlay icons are getting displayed.

However, if I try to open a dialog box from any application, none of these APIs are getting hit and hence overlay icons are not getting set for files inside dialog box. And also I have observed that if I open dialog box it is not showing under explorer app (probably because of that reason since it is not treated as explorer window, for dialog box these APIs are not getting hit). Could anyone please provide solution on how to implement this?

Comment: If you use x64 version of Windows - did you create both 32 and 64 bits version of handler?

Comment: I built 64 bit version of handler @DenisAnisimov

Comment: do we need to create both 32 and 64 bit version of handler?

Comment: If you create 64 bit only handler - 32 bit apps will not be able to use it. You must create and register both versions.

Comment: Hi @DenisAnisimov, the dialog i'm able to open is from 64 bit application only. That should work fine right ?

Comment: one question, if i open dialog box from 64 bit application, will it not come under explorer process?

Comment: If you create and register 64 bit only handler your 64 bit app will use your handler without any problem. If "dialog" means standard windows Open/Save dialog - it always works in context of app, not in context of Explorer.

Comment: is there any work around for us to make that dll work in context of every app which tries to use open/save dialogs?

Comment: Dont understand the last question. If you create and register your handler it will be used by Windows shell subsystem. When any app starts open/save dialog it uses Windows shell subsystem and it uses your handler.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov i thought since open/save dialog works in context of every app so i asked do i need to do some more work around to make that handler work for dialog boxes.

can you please tell me one thing if I registered handler and if it is working for file explorer windows, it should work fine with dialog boxes also right?

Comment: If your handler works correctly in Explorer it means it installed correctly and you dont need to do any additional work. And your handler should work in dialogs of any app without any additional work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with our code, where we are ignoring dialog boxes. Thanks Denis for helping. As Denis mentioned handler works correctly in Explorer if it is installed properly.